# разное количество записей на страницах пагинации django

Tags: python, django

Делаю блог новостей.
Хочу чтобы на первой странице выводилось 5 новостей. В приведенном ниже порядке. А на следующих выводилось по 6 (все квадратики с областями одинаковы).

```css
.news-container {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50fr repeat(2, 25fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 40vh;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.news-element:nth-child(1) {
  background:red;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.news-element:nth-child(2) {
  background:red;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.news-element:nth-child(3) {
  background:red;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.news-element:nth-child(4) {
  background:red;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.news-element:nth-child(5) {
  background:red;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-container">
  <div class="news-element">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="news-element">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="news-element">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="news-element">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="news-element">
    5
  </div>
</div>
```

Как можно сделать так чтобы в пагинации на первой странице выводилось 5 новостей а на остальных по 6?
пагинация сделана на django так

```
class NewsView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name="mysite/news.html"
    paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = "all_news"
    queryset = News.objects.all().order_by("-date_news")
```

я нашел такой [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054981/django-paginating-differently-on-the-first-page) но не понимаю как его добавить в свой код чтобы это работало